# How to step through items in an array on a button press?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Let's say there is an array:

```
var items = ["first", "second", "third"]
```

each time a button is pressed it's supposed to go to the next item in the array.

```
 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
label.text = currentItem
      }
```

I've tried using a for in loop but it just goes through the entire array at once:

```
for item in items {
print(item)
}
```

How to have it so it just goes through the array one item at a time?

Comment: Have an integer index property and increment it after each button press.

Comment: Just posted an example

Comment: @Paulw11 How would you go about doing something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to maintain a variable for what index you're looking at. Then you can just reference the item by it's index. You'll want to make sure that you don't go out of bounds. This can easily be done with modulo.

E.g.

```
var items = ["first", "second", "third"]
var index = 0

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        label.text = items[index]
        index = (index + 1) % items.count
}
```

Edit: Binary Platypus's answer is nicer than mine

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of a counter. Should be pretty straight forward. Something like:

```
var items = ["first", "second", "third"]
var currentIndex: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        currentIndex = currentIndex % items.count
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    label.text = items[currentIndex]
    currentIndex += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way around keeping that variable living there (and cluttering your code) would be to just get the index of the current object and return the next one or the first one, like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let text = label.text, let index = items.index(of: text) else { return }
    label.text = index + 1 < items.count ? items[index + 1] : items[0]
}
```

That makes it so your properties are a little cleaner, and it makes your code a little easier to follow, I think.

Comment: While this will work, as the array gets arbitrarily larger, this method will get slower.

Comment: True, but I'm assuming he's not wanting to use this with an array of 2 mill entries. That's about how many it would need to make it noticeably slower.